# @Embedded List Object Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I need help for embedded a list objects with Hibernate.

This is the Entity Message:

```
@Embeddable
public class Mensaje implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String mensaje;

    private Usuario emisor;

    private Usuario receptor;

    //??????????????????????
    private Calendar ficha;

    private boolean leido;

}
```

This is the Entity User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_USUARIO")
    private int idUsuario;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "CORREO", nullable = false)
    private String correo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="usuario",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Curso> cursos;

    @Column(name = "PAIS")
    private String pais;

    @Column(name = "CIUDAD")
    private String ciudad;

    //????????????????????????????
    @Embedded
    List <Mensaje> mensajes;
}
```

I liked embedded the entity Mensaje in the entity Usuario with Hibernate.
I have tried with ElementoColection but I don't have a good result.
Can you help me please?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

test with this please

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  ....
  ....
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name = "MENSAJE",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
  )
  private List<Mensaje> mensajes;
  ....
  ....
}
@Embeddable
public class Mensaje implements Serializable{
  ....
  ....
  @Column 
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Calendar ficha;
  ....
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with address Embeddable Object

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "streetAndNumber", column = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_STREET_AND_NUMBER")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "addition", column = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ADDITION")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "postalCode", column = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_POSTALCODE", length = 32)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_CITY", length = 256)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "country", column = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_COUNTRY", length = 64))})
private Address address;
```